# File to upload and show on div multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function created to select image from input type="file" and show that uploaded file on a div but the problem is that there will be multiple input file like it will be 3 input file I tied alot but the issue I am facing is only 1 image is showing and the other 2 are not showing.

```js
function head(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#head_shot').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#head").change(function() {
  head(this);
});

function side_profile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#side_profile').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#side_profile").change(function() {
  side_profile(this);
});


function full(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader3 = new FileReader();

    reader3.onload = function(e) {
      $('#full').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#full").change(function() {
  full(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>head shot</h4>
        <img id="head_shot" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Side Profile</h4>
        <img id="side_profile" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Full Length</h4>
        <img id="full" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="picture_sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Head Shot</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="head" id="head">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Side Profile</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="side_profile" id="side_profile">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Full Length</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="full" id="full">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue I change the ID's of your image fields to another value because it is in-conflict with the ID's of your file input.

> General Rule : You cannot have elements with the same ID in DOM

```js
function head(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#head_shot-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#head").change(function() {
  head(this);
});

function side_profile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#side_profile-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#side_profile").change(function() {
  side_profile(this);
});


function full(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader3 = new FileReader();

    reader3.onload = function(e) {
      $('#full-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader3.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#full").change(function() {
  full(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>head shot</h4>
        <img id="head_shot-img" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Side Profile</h4>
        <img id="side_profile-img" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Full Length</h4>
        <img id="full-img" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="picture_sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Head Shot</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="head" id="head">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Side Profile</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="side_profile" id="side_profile">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Full Length</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="full" id="full">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is a suggestion**

I am using [Jquery Multifile](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/) without a problem.

1. The plugin allows you to upload single file or even multiple files.
   Every batch of uploads are grouped and assigned a close button so you can only remove specific files.
2. The next nice feature is the preview of images.

Comment: I tried but was not working for me as in my scenario there will be uploading 3 different files and it cant be multiple and also for image preview is the main reason and due to library confliclation i do not want uant to use more libraries

Comment: is uploading of the three file simultaneous?

Comment: yes you can run my snipet code and see that is the same what will be happening it is in one for but different fields like full body image passport image and etc only 3 images with different input fields i don't how to make understand

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: reader is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 95,
  "colno": 5
}

Comment: @MarkAlan already fixed it. The error is from your original code, using `reader` instead of `reader3`

Answer (score 1):

1. loop through all selected files
2. Make new reader for each file
3. Append new `img` element for each image in photoed container and assign src of new image as current file contents

---

Please check out [**Working Demo at plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sF7IFAhTt0t6mN5MI8i0?p=preview)

```
function showSelectedPhotoes(input) {

  if(!input.files)
    return;

  for(i=0;i<input.files.length;i++)
  {

    var reader3 = new FileReader();    
    reader3.onload = function(e) {
      $('#all_photoes_container').append('<img width="100" height="100" src='+e.target.result+' />')
    };
    reader3.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
  }        
}
```

Comment: can you please update according to my spinet code if possible as I did not quite understood images preview will be in different div's and input type files are in different div

Comment: @MarkAlan. Please prefer plunker for js demos, it facilitates you add any external resources, complete execution. Check my code now. Hope its explained

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, it's an ID conflict. In your first image choice, you have `id="head_shot"` for the img and then `id="head"` for the button. It works fine, because ids are different. However later you have `id="side_profile"` for both image and button, so the script simply ignores the second element with the same id. Here's a fixed version:

```js
function head(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#head_shot').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#head").change(function() {
  head(this);
});

function side_profile(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#side_profile').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#side_profile2").change(function() {
  side_profile(this);
});


function full(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader3 = new FileReader();

    reader3.onload = function(e) {
      $('#full').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader3.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#full2").change(function() {
  full(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>head shot</h4>
        <img id="head_shot" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Side Profile</h4>
        <img id="side_profile" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="img-box">
        <h4>Full Length</h4>
        <img id="full" src="#" alt="your image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="picture_sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Head Shot</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="head" id="head">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Side Profile</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="side_profile2" id="side_profile2">
    </div>

    <div class="lb-put">
      <label>Full Length</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="full" id="full2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. there was also a typo in the reader3 variable in the last function - at some point you lost the "3".

Answer (score 0):

> You can see updated and optimized code [Here...](https://jsfiddle.net/y07gkpo0/29/) I have optimized
>   your code with html and jquery changes that's very useful for you. and
>   you can upload multiple files as well.

**Your HTML Code**

```
<div class="img-sec">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="img-box">
            <h4>head shot</h4>
            <div id="head_shot"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="img-box">
            <h4>Side Profile</h4>
            <div id="side_profile"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="img-box">
            <h4>Full Length</h4>
            <div id="full_length"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="picture_sec">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="lb-put">
         <label>Head Shot</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" name="head_shot" id="head" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="lb-put">
         <label>Side Profile</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" name="side_profile" id="side" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="lb-put">
         <label>Full Length</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" name="full_length" id="full" multiple>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Your jQuery Code:**

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
    var elemPreview = '#' + $(this).attr('name');
    var elemChange = $(this);
    fileupload(elemChange, $(elemPreview));
});

function fileupload(elemChange, elemPreview) {
    if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var dvPreview = elemPreview;
        dvPreview.html("");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
        $(elemChange[0].files).each(function() {
            var file = $(this);
            if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var img = $("<img />");
                    img.attr("style", "height:100px;width: 100px");
                    img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    dvPreview.append(img);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
            } else {
                alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                dvPreview.html("");
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
    }
}
```